# How would you refresh the page like the act of the refresh button in your browser window?

Tags: javascript, reload, page-refresh, browser-refresh

I have searched in Google and on here as I always do, but I have not found the answer I am seeking. This pertains to a specific example and I will reference question : [PHP Trying To Figure out A way to Refresh Session on Browser Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506565/php-trying-to-figure-out-a-way-to-refresh-session-on-browser-refresh) as this is the closest answer I have found.

I created an application that checks a database of approx 100k users for each store and they enter in their customer code to begin their session. After answering the questionnaire, they are redirected back to the start and the session has ended.

Now, everything is working the way I want to and the layout is great. However, I am experiencing timeouts on load, depending on the operating system and browser. Therefore, I would like to add a link that simply refreshes the page (as if you do this with the actual browser refresh button : Chrome Version 34.0.1847.131,  OSX 10.9.2) and everything loads before the timeout occurs.

When redirecting to the session you have two variables: Salesperson and Customer Code. If you simply refresh the page using `location.reload();` , `<a href="javascript:history.go(0)">Click to refresh the page</a>` or any examples I have found thus far, you lose your Salesperson and Customer Code on that page during the refresh. I want to keep those two variables and have a function that acts as if you just hit the refresh button from your browser window. I do realize that fixing the timeout might be the best solution, but I did so for security purposes. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I realize I didn't explain this in depth enough, but everything is working as it should - not using any answers from here or anywhere else (or else I would provide reference/best answer). Thank you for your insight.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Comment: _“you lose your Salesperson and Customer Code on that page during the refresh”_ – well if you need them beyond the scope of the current document, why don’t you put them into the session in the first place …?

Comment: They are in the session in the first place. The problem is that the session is being destroyed on reload.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna avoid timeouts, either you can increase the PHP session limit or, by using a cookie, or you can give an asynchronous call to the same or the home page, without interfering the user's interaction. Use jQuery for that and try loading the home page asynchronously!

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.get("http://example.com/");
}, 100000);
```

Comment: Alright, I'll give this a shot and give an update. Ah, no such luck. I guess I'll just increase the session limit.